# iOS destination simulators missing

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I began typing up this issue and before I submitted it I solved the problem, but since it cost me all morning to resolve and I've seen it before, I figured I'd post it to help others out if they should run into the same issue.

I lost all the destination simulators in a single XCode project save for MacCatalyst and any physical devices. The cause was turning on Mac Catalyst. It's not quite that simple since I am using two different development computers running different version of MacOS. I was quite careful to not have the project open on the two different systems at the same time since that has caused other minor issues issues in the past as well.

I did some work on the second system to resolve issues with MacCatalyst, then closed that and returned to the original computer and discovered all the simulators were missing from the destination drop down. They're there under Windows -> Devices and I can add others but they never show up on the drop down. Other projects work fine.

I'll provide the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

After trying restoring the project file and restoring XCode and deselecting Mac Catalyst all to no avail. I tried de-selecting iPhone and/or iPad and magically the simulators re-appeared. That's all it took.

Comment: After this happened again and I wasted more time trying all the wrong things, I stopped and looked at the simulators. At the same time that I added MacCatalyst, I guess I also changed the target for iOS development to a different iOS version and that is actually what caused the destination devices to disappear since they were all running an earlier version of iOS so naturally they wouldn't be available as targets. As soon as I changed the iOS version back to what it was, the simulators showed up again.